# Urdu text, English equation counter

Tags: page-numbering

I am writing an engineering text book in Urdu using XeLatex and Polyglossia. I am using `amsmath` package so all the equations are in normal English. I want the equation numbers, page numbers and figure numbers to be displayed in normal English too. I have been able to do so using

```
\renewcommand*{\theequation}{\textenglish{{\small{\arabic{equation}}}}}
```

However, `amsmath` automatically puts equation numbers in round brace. These braces do not fit well around the equation numbers that I generated with the above `\renewcommand` strategy. If i use

```
\makeatletter
 \def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{ \big ]  {\small #1} \big [  \@@italiccorr}}
\makeatother
```

command to increase the size of the brace, it becomes too large.

Comment: You must put a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: since in the revised `\maketag@@@` expansion you have restricted `\small` to just the setting of `#1`, you can probably just forget about `\big` and let the brackets come out at the "normal" size.